# how to avoid redirection in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, redirect

I have a function name HideN which triggers when user click on a link like shown below

```
<a href="<?php echo $dn5['link']; ?>" onclick="HideN('<?php echo $dn5['id'];?>','<?php echo $dn5['from_user'];?>')" class="media">
```

this gives me

```
<a href="/page/example" onclick="HideN('25','username')" class="media">
```

Now i want to send an ajax request onclick, then redirect the user to `/page/example` but it always abort the ajax request and redirect the page

```
function HideN(t, a) {
    var e = {
        id: t,
        user: a
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.example.com/ajax/hideN?status=hideIt",
        data: e,
        success: function(t) {}
    })
};
```

How can i first send an ajax request then redirect the page after success response

the link is dynamically generated from database, every link will be different

Comment: Why not just submit a regular form, if all you want to do is redirect anyway

Answer (score 1):

You need prevent the default click by `event.preventDefault()` and redirect on ajax success

```
<a href="" onclick="HideN(event, '<?php echo $dn5['id'];?>','<?php echo $dn5['from_user'];?>', '<?php echo $dn5['link'];?>')" class="media">

        function HideN(ev,t, a, lk) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var e = {
                id: t,
                user: a
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://www.example.com/ajax/hideN?status=hideIt",
                data: e,
                success: function(t) {
                window.location.href = lk;
}
            })
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i found myself

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="HideN('<?php echo $dn5['id'];?>','<?php echo $dn5['from_user'];?>','<?php echo $dn5['link'];?>')" class="media">
```

which gives me

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="HideN('25','username','/page/link')" class="media">

function HideN(t, a, c) {
    var e = {
        id: t,
        user: a
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.example.com/ajax/hideN?status=hideIt",
        data: e,
        success: function(t) {
            window.location.href = c;
        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting the link in the anchor tag like:

```
<a href="/page/example" onclick="HideN('25','username')" class="media">
```

you can put `href="javascript:void(0);"` so that the link won't actually try to change the page:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="HideN('25','username')" class="media">
```

Now your ajax call will complete, and you can redirect inside the `success` function.

```
success: function(t) {
    window.location.href = "<?php echo $dn5['link']; ?>";
}
```

If the javascript is in a separate .js file that you can't change through PHP, you can change the link to:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="HideN('<?php echo $dn5['id'];?>','<?php echo $dn5['from_user'];?>','<?php echo $dn5['link']; ?>')" class="media">
```

and change the javascript to:

```
function HideN(t, a, link) {
    var e = {
        id: t,
        user: a
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.example.com/ajax/hideN?status=hideIt",
        data: e,
        success: function(t) {
            window.location.href = link;
        }
    })
};
```

Now the link will be passed as a parameter to the `HideN` function, and can be used to redirect inside the `success` function.

Another option for the link, as suggested in a comment on the question [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134845) is to use the `HideN` function as the `href` value:

```
<a href="javascript:HideN('<?php echo $dn5['id'];?>','<?php echo $dn5['from_user'];?>','<?php echo $dn5['link']; ?>')" class="media">
```

Edit: Changed to `href="javascript:void(0);"` instead of `href="#"` after comments and further research suggest that it is better.

Comment: You need to write `preventDefault()` befor `ajax`.

Comment: @Mohammad Do you always have to do that when preventing a link from going somewhere, or does using `javascript:void(0);` remove that need?

Comment: `#` href will reset your window scroll

Comment: @jonhopkins I cant see `javascript:void(0);` in your code.

Comment: @Mohammad I didn't have it anywhere. I was asking if using it would make it so I don't have to use `preventDefault()`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to redirect the user only if the ajax is successful then place the redirect window.location.href = 'your redirect page' in the success callback.

Otherwise if you need to redirect either is successful or not, use complete callback.

```
   function HideN(t, a) {
        var e = {
            id: t,
            user: a
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://www.example.com/ajax/hideN?status=hideIt",
            data: e,
            success: function(response) { window.location.href = "http://google.com"}
        })
    };
```

Later edit @codenoire : you should change the href attribute to "javascript: void(0)" or you can use preventDefault

Comment: the link is dynamically generated from database, every link will be different

Comment: Then you must return that link to client side.

Comment: When you will hit an endpoint with this ajax request probably you are able to compute the link that is dynamically generated. So what you need to do is to return that link in response object and that object will be available in your ajax success callback

Comment: This is a good example.  BUT you should change the href attribute to "javascript: void(0)" because you don't want the browser to actually go to the value specified in the href attribute.

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="<?php echo $dn5['link']; ?>" onclick="HideN('<?php echo $dn5['id'];?>','<?php echo $dn5['from_user'];?>', '<?php echo $dn5['link']; ?>')" class="media">
```

Then have this function:

```
function HideN(t, am, link) {
    var e = {
        id: t,
        user: a
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.example.com/ajax/hideN?status=hideIt",
        data: e,
        success: function(t) {
            window.location = link;
        }
    })
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

add

```
return false;
```

to your **HideN** function last line. or

use

```
preventDefault
```

to stop click event default behavior

> https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: That won't help. You have to return false from the event handler function. Not some callback that might be executed at some point in the future.

Comment: sorry you need to use it in HideN function. you need to stop click function default behavior to prevent redirection

Comment: Much simpler to use something like `href="javascript:;"` then

Comment: yes good solution indeed, i just point out the redirection reason,

Comment: No, it needs to go in the onclick function, not the HideN function

Comment: @vp_arth — That violates [a basic principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) of good design.

Comment: Yes inline JS, even CSS sometime confusing and not clean design approach.